# What is the EASIEST way to merge several delimited text files / ignore all 1st row (headers) below the first master file?

Tags: database, merge

And by easiest, I don't mean shelling out $80 for Bulk File Merger.  Is there other freeware or some simple code to merge SEVERAL files at once?

Thanks!

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: by merge, do you mean concatenate or something more complex?

Comment: You tagged the question with `database`, but your title says text files? Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

In DOS you can use the more command: 
    http://www.computerhope.com/morehlp.htm

the more command is probably limited to files of 64k or less in size.
I believe the syntax would be

```
more  +1 (filespec) >> outfile
```

In unix you can use cat and sed to accomplish the same thing
    http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

alternatively, in windows you can write a shell script - this one from msdn does most of it...

```
Const ForReading = 1 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("output.txt") 

strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set FileList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name='z:\Scripts\Test'} Where " _ 
        & "ResultClass = CIM_DataFile") 

For Each objFile In FileList 
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Name, ForReading)  
    strText = objTextFile.ReadAll 
    objTextFile.Close 
    objOutputFile.WriteLine strText 
Next 

objOutputFile.Close
```

The one thing left for you to do would be to remove the first line of each file by modifying the strText variable, which holds the text of each file as they are processed.